# How to store articles into a single file in React Native News app?

Tags: react-native

A news article is a HTML format with multiple images and text, maybe audio. How can I export some articles to a file (maybe json, realm, sqlite... whatever is the best, I don't know) and then someone can import that file to read those articles?
I did some research and we can convert image to base64. But I am not sure it's a good idea if the image is large.